# MSSQL UPDATE SELECT and SET Query not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=:username SET profilePicturePath=:pic");
$query->bindParam(":pic", $_FILES['profilePic']['name']);
$pic = "hellow";
$query->bindParam(":username", $pic);
$query->execute();
```

The pic variable is just for testing. Anyway, I can confirm that username=:username comes out true, it is just a problem with the reset of the statement. As I said, not a problem with anything except for the statement itself. I am using php7 on a mssql 2008 database. Thanks for the input!

EDIT
Replace code with this, still doesn't work :

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=@username    SET profilePicturePath=@pic");
$pic = "hellow";
$query->bindParam("@pic", $pic);
$query->bindParam("@username", $_SESSION['Username']);
$query->execute();
```

SELECT all from users works, but this below doesn't work either :

```
"UPDATE Users SET profilePicturePath = 'Silver Magic' WHERE Username = 'ekampel';"
```

Comment: try to replace ':' to '@' in where condition. for eg:- username=@username

Comment: That is not even close to update syntax.

Comment: @IvanStarostin So what would the right syntax be then...

Comment: @Wyatt right as msdn says!

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's not much help. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Wyatt That's not much effort of you. Not at all.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Lol what? Haha

Answer (score 0):

Try Query as

```
"UPDATE Users SET profilePicturePath=@pic WHERE username=@username"
```

Comment: Tried that query, still not changing anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN pages, updating in SELECT statement is not allowed by SQL Server's SELECT syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.110).aspx.
You have to do two separate statements, one for select:

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=:username");
$pic = "hellow";
$query->bindParam(":username", $pic);
$query->execute();
```

and another for update:

```
$query = $database->prepare("UPDATE Users SET profilePicturePath=:pic where username = :username");
$query->bindParam(":pic", $_FILES['profilePic']['name']);
$query->bindParam(":username", $pic);
$query->execute();
```

Also, to make updates work, make sure that user in target database has UPDATE permission. You may grant update and insert permissions by adding user to `db_datawrite` database role in target database:

```
USE target_database; ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER user_name;
```